# How do I filter countries/us/us-all-all to only show ca and nv?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I can get all US counties and I can get one state, but I can't get all the counties from two states into the same map. Here is my R code:

```
hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all", data = dataframe, value = "value1",
  joinBy = c("name"), name = "Name",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),
  tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = "%"),
  pointFormat = "County: {point.name}<br/>{point.value1}")
```

I tried downloading each state's data:

```
camapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-ca-all"))
nvmapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-nv-all"))
```

Then combining into one data set, but then `hcmap` errors because it's not a URL.

I can also download and filter the whole US map:

```
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-all-all"))
canvmap <- filter(mapdata, `hc-key` == "us-ca*")
```

but get the same problem.

Is there a way to filter the US county map to specific states within the `hcmap` function?

Comment: Could you describe what exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean saying "all US counties" etc.? Also, could you provide your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have so far--but I can only get CA and NV in one map...

```
 camapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-ca-all"))
 nvmapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-nv-all"))
 states2<-join(camapdata,nvmapdata,by=c("fips"), type="full",match="all")
 setnames(states2, old=c("hc-a2"), new=c("STABBR"))
 setnames(states2, old=c("hc-middle-y"), new=c("HCMIDDLE"))
 XXX<-sqldf("select * from states2  where STABBR in ('CA','OR')")

 library(highcharter)
 hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all", data = states2, value = "HCMIDDLE",
  joinBy = c("name"), name = "Name",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),
  tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = "%"),
  pointFormat = "County: {point.name}<br/>{point.value1}")
```

Comment: This looks like what I was attempting, but with the joining part I was missing. I'm trying to duplicate it, but get the error `unused arguments (old = c("hc-a2"), new = c("STABBR"))`?

Comment: I got it to work with my data! Thank you! I changed it a bit to merge with my dataset: 
```
camapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-ca-all")) nvmapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-nv-all")) states2<-join(camapdata,nvmapdata,by=c("fips"), type="full",match="all") states2$State <- ifelse(grepl("us-ca*", states2$hc-key), "California", "Nevada") CountyData <- merge(states2, mydata, by.x = c("State","name"), by.y = c("State", "name")) 
```
This allowed me to merge data by state and county since counties have the same name across states.